# Foreach e Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Caros colegas.

Estou trazendo do banco Mysql duas perguntas, do qual o usuário cadastrará as respectivas perguntas. Vejam:

```
....
<input type="hidden" name="Pergunta[]" value="<?php echo $idPergunta; ?>">
Pergunta: <?php echo $jmPerguntas->Perguntas; ?><br>
Resposta: <input type="text" name="Respostas[]" class="formRespostas">
....
```

Para resgatar o valor da resposta estou usando o foreach, mas como eu sei que resposta se refere a qual pergunta?

```
foreach($respostas as $resposta){
      $sqlCadastrar = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO respostas VALUES(null,".$pergunta.",".$usuario.",'".$resposta."',NOW())");         
    }
```

Comment: Não percebi qual é o problema.

Comment: @Jose.Marcos, podes colar o HTML gerado ao invés do PHP no primeiro bloco?

Comment: A dúvida dele está relacionado ao retorno dos dados, quando ele já tem a lista de respostas, mas ele quer saber como ele sabe qual resposta é de qual pergunta :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro como percebeste isso dali?

Comment: @JorgeB. Pela lógica dele é 1 resposta pra 1 pergunta, não é múltipla-escolha, então no `for` dele é muito estranho ele iterar `$respostas` passando um `$pergunta` no insert, então o que falei é a unica hipótese.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro muito bem visto, mas é melhor esperar pelo AP para ter a certeza...

Comment: É mais ou menos isso. Tenho duas perguntas que foram cadastradas no banco de dados. Ex.: 

Quem descobriu o Brasil?
Quem descobriu a América?

O usuário irá responder as perguntas, porém preciso cadastrar as perguntas e suas respectivas respostas no banco de dados. Estou tentando usar o foreach(), porém só consegui cadastrar as respostas corretamente, mas as perguntas não.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Quero agradecer os colegas que tentaram me ajudar. Como faço pra postar a solução? Posso responder minha própria pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Segue abaixo:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['Pergunta']); $i++){
     $sqlCadastrar = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO respostas VALUES(null,".$_POST['Pergunta'][$i].",".$usuario.",'".$_POST['Respostas'][$i]."',NOW())");     
}

 ....
<input type="hidden" name="Pergunta[]" value="<?php echo $idPergunta; ?>">
Pergunta: <?php echo $jmPerguntas->Perguntas; ?><br>
Resposta: <input type="text" name="Respostas[]" class="formRespostas">
....
```

Obrigado a todos!